# IBM MQ Series reply message not immediately visible in reply queue

Tags: vb.net, ibm-mq

I am building a tool that puts messages on a queue and put the response/reply on another (normally a stub queue)

All is working fine but it seems that the amount of time it takes for the reply message to be received and put the stub queue is longer than it really is. `

```
Try
        PublicMQVariable.MQMessage_Reply = New MQMessage
        PublicMQVariable.MQMessage_Reply.CorrelationId = PublicMQVariable.MQMessage_Request.MessageId
        PublicMQVariable.MQMessage_Reply.MessageType = MQC.MQMT_REPLY
        PublicMQVariable.MQGetMessageOptions_Response = New MQGetMessageOptions
        PublicMQVariable.MQGetMessageOptions_Response.Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT + MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
        PublicMQVariable.MQGetMessageOptions_Response.MatchOptions = MQC.MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID
        PublicMQVariable.MQGetMessageOptions_Response.WaitInterval = PublicMQVariable.MyTimeOut
        PublicMQVariable.MyStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
        PublicMQVariable.MQQueue_Reply.Get(PublicMQVariable.MQMessage_Reply, PublicMQVariable.MQGetMessageOptions_Reply)
        PublicMQVariable.MyStopwatch.Stop()
        PublicMQVariable.MyReplyMessage = PublicMQVariable.MQMessage_Reply.ReadString(PublicMQVariable.MQMessage_Reply.MessageLength)
    Catch ex As MQException
        MsgBox("MQException: compCode: " & ex.CompCode.ToString() & " Reason: " + ex.Reason.ToString() & " - " & ex.Message)
        MQDisconnectAndClose()
        Return
    End Try
```

The code above is just the part where the response is 'get'`
The Stopwatch says the reply is received in +/- 2000 milliseconds but when I browse the reply queue then the reply message is only present after about 18 seconds (looking at my watch and browsing the queue constantly)

1. This the use of the stopwatch accurate?
2. Why does it take so long for the message to be visible in the reply queue?
3. Is there away to capture the reply message as soon as it generated by the system? (before it is even put to the reply queue)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MQExplorer to browse the reply message? MQExplorer has a pre-defined refresh interval of 15 seconds. After every 15 seconds, MQExplorer refreshes the contents of the view. It will display the messages present in a queue, latest channel status etc.

Comment: Shashi, I don't think I understand your question. Is MQExporer an IBM Websphere function?

Comment: MQExplorer is a WebSphere MQ Administration Tool. I was trying to understand how you are browsing the reply queue.

Comment: Oh, no I am not using MQExplorer. I have code normal 'get message' code for that.